# Class Design: Car and Road

Tags: class, object, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design Car and Road objects for a game design I'm working on.

The idea is for AI Cars (as well as the Player controlled car) to recognize when they traverse dotted lines or straight lines on the Roads.
I'd like to be able to build a Variable Lane Road for Unity3D with the appropriate flags and sub objects so that the Cars recognize where they are and when and how they traverse or take turns etc' etc'

For example, a Road can have a single direction or be in both directions.
For each direction there can be a number of lanes. Lanes allow cars to overtake each other (meaning a dotted line between the lanes).
If it's a bi directional road, then there's a line between the two lanes - optionally and ideally, if there's more than one lane on any of the directions, then the line that separates the directional lanes is straight.
By default, there should be a flag that draws the line according to an isOvertakingAllowed boolean flag.

The most important part is that the Car objects need to know what lane they are on or if they are on a lane separating line, and what type this separation is (overtaking allowed or not).
That's the hard part, to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131515/ai_madness_using_ai_to_bring_.php?page=1) on gamasutra with description of the model that was used for opencity, and how the different agents (standard car, racing car, pedestrian...) could use it. It may gives you some pointers or ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you implement a `Lane`, which have a direction of travel. Then implement a `Road` which has a collection of points, a path defining it's shape, and distance, and a collection of `Lane` objects that follow that path. Whether the road is one-way or two-way becomes a matter of which, and how many lanes they have.

In this case, a `Car` travels on a `Road` in a given direction, following the lane that it's in. It can only switch to other lanes that have compatible directions of travel (i.e. that are heading in the same direction as the car), unless the car turns around.

You might also have a special point in a `Road` called an `Intersection` which is a connection point for multiple `Lanes`, and somehow specify which `Lanes` a `Car` can transition to and from when it's at the `Intersection`.

That's a rough outline, but I think those are the basic relationships between the objects that you present, and should get you started.

Comment: Indeed, that's a good start.

However, my game design is a bit more complicated. It's okay for a car to go ON a separation line - in which case various actions the play takes can be rewarded.

Basically, the Car objects should NOT be constricted by the Lanes or Roads. Only guided by them and Inform them (by that I mean, for the Cars to know where they are and what traffic violation they might be doing).

Comment: So, use the lane/road as the guide for turning, etc. but allow some offset from that hard line, that goes out as far as you want. For example, in my Pedestrians tech demo, the pedestrians use A* for pathfinding their way through a maze, and the paths they get back are 8-directional based paths. However, they're allowed to deviate from those paths in order to turn and avoid each other. Here's a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEY9MLpDkGE&list=UU7iqR7zggnpvZySau81qCqw&index=2&feature=plcp